# Does Facebook have a maximum number of API connections?

Tags: facebook

If the answer is yes, then what is it?

By maximum number of connectioned allowed per application I mean how many instances of the same api/key can be used to get the friends list at any one time, will Facebook block too many requests?

**EDIT** I have been looking at http://developers.facebook.com/ but have not been able to find the answer to my question there.

Comment: Isn't this something you should be looking at http://developers.facebook.com/ for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From their [Policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

> If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds please contact us as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day).

Answer (score 1):

The only information I was able to find is something in a forum.

http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-Facebook-Open-Graph-API-rate-limit

> After some testing and discussion with the Facebook platform team,
>   there is no official limit I'm aware of or can find in the
>   documentation. However, I've found 600 calls per 600 seconds, per
>   token & per IP to be about where they stop you. I've also seen some
>   application based rate limiting but don't have any numbers.
>
> As a general rule, one call per second should not get rate limited. On
>   the surface this seems very restrictive but remember you can batch
>   certain calls and use the subscription API to get changes.

Comment: It seems like they don't have an hard cap on 600 requests per 600 second period anymore. I started 10 threads hammering the API and performed around ~2000req/min (sorry Facebook!), did not get blocked.

Comment: @RobinWassén-Andersson Is this still valid?

Comment: @RobinWassén-Andersson have you hammered lately? and what about if all requests are made via an application token via php instead of javascript?

Comment: @ShawnECarter I have not tried since I wrote that comment, and when I did that test it was with an application token from C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how many API requests your users can have a day if you go to your Insights page and click on "Diagnostics". You can also see some other request statistics if you click on "Performance".
http://www.facebook.com/insights